# java.lang.NullPointerException при попытке получить сущность по Id

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

Сущность:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.domain;

import com.igorgorbunov3333.core.entities.enums.Proceeding;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 03.04.2016.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "cases")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getAllCases", query = "SELECT c FROM Case c JOIN FETCH c.client JOIN FETCH c.firstInstance " +
            "JOIN FETCH c.secondInstance JOIN FETCH c.thirdInstance JOIN FETCH c.category")
})
public class Case {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "case_number")
    private String caseNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_instance_id")
    private FirstInstance firstInstance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_instance_id")
    private SecondInstance secondInstance;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "third_instance_id")
    private ThirdInstance thirdInstance;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Proceeding proceeding;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "closing_date")
    private Date closingDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    private float price;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCaseNumber() {
        return caseNumber;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public FirstInstance getFirstInstance() {
        return firstInstance;
    }

    public SecondInstance getSecondInstance() {
        return secondInstance;
    }

    public ThirdInstance getThirdInstance() {
        return thirdInstance;
    }

    public Proceeding getProceeding() {
        return proceeding;
    }

    public Date getClosingDate() {
        return closingDate;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCaseNumber(String caseNumber) {
        this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void setFirstInstance(FirstInstance firstInstance) {
        this.firstInstance = firstInstance;
    }

    public void setSecondInstance(SecondInstance secondInstance) {
        this.secondInstance = secondInstance;
    }

    public void setThirdInstance(ThirdInstance thirdInstance) {
        this.thirdInstance = thirdInstance;
    }

    public void setProceeding(Proceeding proceeding) {
        this.proceeding = proceeding;
    }

    public void setClosingDate(Date closingDate) {
        this.closingDate = closingDate;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Вот здесь получаю `NullPointerException`:

```
public Case findById(long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Case.class, id);
}
```

По таблице базы данных сверял - id тот, что надо, но сущность не находится. Все сущности получаю нормально:

```
public List<Case> findAll() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getAllCases");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Контейнер - Spring, поставщик - Hibernate.

Comment: Включите параметр показывать sql: `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` и выполните этот запрос отдельно с Вашим id, результат возвращает нужные данные?

Comment: Включен, не возвращает!

Comment: Попробуйте получить таким запросом: `entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Case c WHERE c.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .getResultList();`, но если не поможет, добавьте код на гитхаб, чтоб воспроизвести у себя

Comment: @MrFylypenko спасибо за комментарии. Решил проблемн. В сервлете создавал `CaseService` так: `private CaseService caseService = new CaseServiceImpl()`. Надо было так: `private CaseService caseService =  SpringAppContextManager.getAppContext()
            .getBean("CaseService", CaseService.class);`